# Jpa Query Works on Jetty Embedded, but doesn't run when deployed to Jetty

Tags: java, jetty, persistence, openjpa

The query is

```
em.createQuery("select bp from BlogPost bp WHERE ?1 MEMBER OF bp.categories")
                .setParameter(1, c)
                .getResultList();
```

In my integrated test container it runs fine, it's on a custom Jetty Instance I have in my code.

When deployed using gradle jettyRun or jettyRunWar however, it can't run the query above, I get a blank result set and the following error.

> 4528  Simple  WARN   [1241194115@qtp-739763767-0] openjpa.Runtime -
>   Supplied user parameters "[1]" do not match expected parameters "[]"
>   for the prepared query "PreparedQuery: [select bp from BlogPost bp
>   WHERE ?1 MEMBER OF bp.categories] --> [SELECT t0.id, t2.id,
>   t2.accessLevel, t3.id, t3.address1, t3.address2, t3.city , t3.country,
>   t3.homephone, t3.mobilephone, t3.postal, t3.province, t2.identifier,
>   t2.password_md5, t0.body, t0.dateCreated, t0.datePublished, t0.title
>   FROM BlogPost t0 INNER JOIN BlogPost_BlogCategory t1 ON t0.id =
>   t1.BLOGPOST_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN User t2 ON t0.author = t2.id LEFT OUTER
>   JOIN ContactInfo t3 ON t2.contact Info = t3.id WHERE (t1.CATEGORIES_ID
>   IS NULL)]".

I could just code around it, but the MEMBER OF makes it a lot simpler, it's strange that depending on how it's deployed in the web container it runs differently.

Answer (score 0):

This is some sort of bug in OpenJpa.

I thought, I'm using JPA so let's just switch to hibernate and see how it goes down, hibernate is a bit more strict and forced me to negligible change my annotations and classes a bit. But 20 minutes later the problem was fixed. Not only that but other problems that were hidden got fixed as well.

So I think I'm just going to call Hibernate my solution here. If there is a parameter or a config or something maybe the collective wants the information, but my resolution is met.